# Facebook login in ionic

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I wonder what kind of workflow other people have had when logging in with facebook.

I have an app that requires signup. People can also signup by logging in via facebook. That part has been integrated.

However, when a user signs in with facebook (which means: facebook page open and requires login), my workflow
takes the user to a screen where he needs to create a username (as having a username is required).

After the user picked up a username, then I create this new user, save the facebook token and generate a password.
Now, automatically, the user will be logged in in my app.

Next time the user opens the app, in background, I will login the user taking the email (which originally was fetched from facebook) and the password, which are stored in local storage.

But what if the user logs out or delete the app and reinstall it? I have seen that this happens some times. In that case, the workflow (if the user clicks on facebook login on my app) will take the user again to facebook. And after he logs in in facebook, he will come back to my screen where he can choose a username. This is bad. Because I already created an account for the user with the email binded to that facebook account.

Of course, I can understand that this user that logs in via facebook already has an account. But what can I do? Can I just login him in background? Are there any security implications (yeah, my app is not that sensitive, but I would prefer to use best practice).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the user already logged in once, the expected behavior is to be logged in again on future visits to the app. If the user passed the Facebook login, you can safely assume that it is the same user imho.